# ¿Cómo puedo crear una variable global en el kernel de Kaggle/Ipython para llamar en una celda del cuaderno con $variable?

Tags: linux, variables, variables-globales, ipython, environment

Intente crear una variable en mi Kaggle console para utilisarlo sin revelarlo cuando comparto mi codigo pero ningun de mis intentos exiten:

```
export secret_value_0=hello
SyntaxError
  File "<ipython-input-8-1c4a6fde9da4>", line 1
    export secret_value_0=hello
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Entonces como crear una variable para puedar llamarla en una celda del notebook como:

! wandb login $secret_value_0

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que veo:

```
os.environ["secret_value_0"] = hello
```

Referencia: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971312/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-python